# extracting argument value from JS function call with cheerio

Tags: postman, html-parsing, cheerio

a postman request returns html page. using cheerio in postman tests, i get to the tag from which i need to extract a more specific value, the cheerio code is:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("the_tag", $('body script'));
```

which gives me:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > $(function () {
some_func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
});
<  / script >
```

now what would be the correct cheerio code to get the value of arg3 in the some_func call?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this can be done with Cheerio.
I would use a combination of regex and `split`

Storing the snippet you got from cheerio in a variable: `let snippet = '< script type = "text/javascript" > $(function () {some_func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);});'`

Defining a regex which returns a list of all arguments of `some_func`: `let regex = new RegExp('some_func\\((.*?)\\)')`, see https://regex101.com/r/VnXA8J/1

Getting the match of the regex: `let match = regex.exec(snippet);`

Getting the third argurment with `split` and removing spaces with `trim`: `let thirdArgument = match[1].split(",")[2].trim()`

Logging the result to the console: `console.log(thirdArgument) // "arg3"`

```
let snippet = '< script type = "text/javascript" > $(function () {some_func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);});'

let regex = new RegExp('some_func\\((.*?)\\)')

let match = regex.exec(snippet);

let thirdArgument = match[1].split(",")[2].trim()

console.log(thirdArgument) // "arg3"
```

Comment: thank you, this works nicely! though only as long as there's the string constant as in your first line. when i replace that with the text to be captured, $('body script').text(), then it doesn't. how would i fix that?

Comment: i think i figured it out, there were occurences of multiple spaces in the string, this seems to somehow break the splitting statement. using $('body script').text().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ') instead, to replace them with single spaces, did the trick :)